# How to make enemies follow the player all around the screen in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, artificial-intelligence, game-physics, path-finding

Okay, so I've got some code to make my enemies follow the player in my XNA game, but they only follow the player until the player is in front of them. If the player moves past an enemy, it will stop moving towards him. Instead they will continuously move up and down with the player.

The code I've used is this:

```
         Vector2 direction = player.Position - goblins[i].Position;
         direction.Normalize();
         Vector2 velocity = direction * goblins[i].enemyMoveSpeed;
         goblins[i].Position += velocity;
```

(ignore the goblins bit, I've just replaced the graphics)

Not entirely sure where to go with it, any ideas?

Comment: That code looks fine to me. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and see if the values are updated correctly? Maybe the values are being manipulated outside of the current code.

Comment: By the way: What exactly is `goblins[i].enemyMoveSpeed`? Is it a `float` or a `Vector2`?

Comment: You sir are a hero. I accidentally left another line of code specifying a movement rule that meant they would effectively move at twice the speed to the left but not able to move right at all. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: goblins[i].enemyMoveSpeed is a float, just the speed at which enemies move

Answer (score 2):

Tom, hello, how are you?

Here you have 2 examples that helped me a lot:

1. Chase & Evade (http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/chase_evade) This is a Microsoft sample that shows how to implement several simple behaviors for AI, including chasing, evading, and wandering.
2. Adding a field of view to enemies (http://robotfootgames.com/xna-tutorials/5-xna-platformer-starter-kit-field-of-view-for-enemies) Related to number 1 sample and to Plaformer starter kit